# Where place password in Wake on LAN (WOL) protocole?

Tags: packet, wake-on-lan

i was searched on the internet since a long time but i don't found how to introduce an eventual station password in the Wake On Lan magic packet, i hope we can help me, so somebody know how to manage the station password in WOL protocole ?

here's how I created my magic packet:

```
0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
[ 16 times MAC address ]
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia, you must append the 6 byte password after the MAC address :

```
0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
[ 16 times MAC address ]
[ Password ]
```

But only a few hardware implements this feature.
If you're router or computer don't support magic packet password, maybe you can do it yourself (using an open source router, DD-WRT compatible, or a wake on lan repeater made with an Arduino or Raspberry Pi).
See this tutorial : http://www.finalclap.com/tuto/arduino-wake-on-lan-repeater-80/